# Laravel: download() does not trigger file save dialog

Tags: php, apache, download, laravel-8

My laravel(8.0) test code (web.php):

```
Route::get(
  '/dddd',
  fn () =>
  response()->download(public_path('version.pdf'), null, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])
);
```

This code works perfert in my homestead test environment. The browser will popup a file dialog and ask user to save the file.

But when I put this application inside docker (image: php:8.0-apache-buster), the popup dialog will not show and the browser open the file directly with binary characters. I tried to catch the response in chrome, the response headers is like following:

```
Request URL: http://redtrain.test:8080/dddd
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.10.10:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1305
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2022 05:39:56 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.14
```

I noticed that header is not consistent with my code, maybe it is updated by Apache? Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: I see from your question that Homestead is better than Docker.